# How to parse text file with 2 delimiters

Tags: excel

I have a text file that is pipe-delimited that also has a new line indicator (`START_OF_RECORD`). The values are enclosed with single quotes and line breaks are expected in the 5th field. Notice the values with line breaks are still enclosed in single quotes though

Does excel have a native way to handle this? As far as I know, excel can only take in a custom delimiter. It's the `START_OF_NEW_LINE` that is causing the issue.

---

Sample screen shot of desired output, followed by input, followed by input as text.

[image]

```
|'START_OF_LINE'|'Key 1'|'Key 2'|'Key 3'|'text1
text2
text3
text4
text5'|'Date'|'END_OF_LINE'|'ID 1'|'ID 2'|'ID 3'|'ID 4'|'ID 5'|
|'START_OF_LINE'|'Key 1'|'Key 2'|'Key 3'|'text5
text6
text7
text8
text9'|'Date'|'END_OF_LINE'|'ID 1'|'ID 2'|'ID 3'|'ID 4'|'ID 5'|
```

---

I'm sure this can be hacked together with some tedious VBA but am really hoping there is a better way to do this before starting to write out code. I just have no idea how to handle the new line field using native functionality in excel

Comment: It might be doable in Power Query / Get & Transform but not sure.

Comment: I think this file was optimized for some kind of SQL uploader, but I don't have access to one @BigBen - thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 0):

The case seems to be consistent. I've used notepad++ find and replace function on the text. and it seems to deliver what you need.

1. copy the text above and paste in notepad++ > replace "|\r\n|" with "|·|" **
2. then > replace "\n" with "\n||||"
3. then > replace "|·|" with "|\n"
4. remove the 1st "|"
5. copy n paste into excel, with "|" as delimiter.

Done.

**[Note:\r may not appear in the original file.. it is there in the copy paste activity.. omit it if it is not applicable]

If all the above can be executed using regex, then it is just a line of code away.. ( :